# Работа с массивами. Механика

Tags: php, массивы, динамические-массивы

Есть очень интересная задача. Занимаюсь сайтом доставки пиццы, где есть такое понятие как модификатор(допустим добавить колбасу).

```
//артикулы товаров
$product[0] = "10000";  //Пицца
$product[1] = "10001";  //Добавка к пицце - сыр
$product[2] = "10002";  //Добавка к пицце - бекон
$product[3] = "10003";  //Сок

//количество товаров
$product_kol[0] = "1";
$product_kol[1] = "1";
$product_kol[2] = "1";
$product_kol[3] = "1";

//модификаторы, если есть 
$product_mod[1] = "0";  //товар с ключом 1 является модификатором товара с ключом 0
$product_mod[2] = "0";  //товар с ключом 2 является модификатором товара с ключом 0
```

Это все интегрировано с системой Frontpad, работа через API.
Так вот, как реализовать работу с модификаторами?
Ибо я с сайта отправляю артикул пиццы, добавки, количество, но как поступить с 
**$product_mod[1] = "0"**? А если две пиццы с модификатором? Т.е нужно узнать сначала каким - то образом, к какой именно пицце добавить модификатор, а потом еще и узнать ключ самого модификатора.
В общем я потерян и растерян. Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Надо отправлять соответствие "ИД продукта - ИД модификатора"

Comment: @u_mulder, если не сложно, можно немного подробнее? просто от этой задачки у меня мозг взрывается, поскольку я еще совсем новичок).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего создавать объект(Ассоциативный массив), в котором по ключу товара будет модификатор.
$product_mod["Гавайская"] = "Колбаса"